# How do I read a txt file that is separated by space in R?

Tags: r, read.csv, read.table

Here is the code I have, but for some reason, I'm getting an error when I run it

```
data <- read.table("numbers.txt",header=TRUE,sep = "")
data
```

The error is:
Warning message:

```
In read.table("numbers.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "") :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'numbers.txt'
```

Comment: Check your text file, the error is indicating that the data is not rectangular (that is, each row doesn't have the same number of variables).

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning. Is `data` created?

Comment: My txt file is the following :  123 456 789

Comment: `incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on '***.txt'` looks like the empty final line (needed on some system as linux) is missing from you text file. Try to edit it by hand as a quick fix.

Comment: Could you provide the content of the file "numbers.txt"?